# angular and the correct way to load a webpage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Been trying to figure this one out.
So have a webpage where I want to load another webpage (or more specifically, a page from another webpage) into a div. It is basically a new ticker that I want to display.

My problem is, the actual address is stored mongodb, and I can retreieve it all ok. Lets say that it is http://www.google.com

It is store in Webcont.url (there is a Webcont.name as well which contains a short name for each page)
I would have thought I would be able to do something along the lines of

```
    <div ng-include="Webcont.url"></div>
    //or
    <object data="Webcont.url"></object>
//or even
<object data="{{Webcont.url}}></object>
```

Or any other model, but I can not for the life of me find a way to do it. It does not help that the search terms are url, include, load, object and data. Terms that throws up a lot of hits on google :)

Comment: A fiddle or jsBin would help here. What errors are being thrown (if any)? Have you looked at ng-bind-html-unsafe? Angular is careful about what gets directly inserted into the DOM and so that may have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just use `ng-include` to load content from another domain, as that's a security risk. You can work around that using the [$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(value)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#trustAsResourceUrl). The [$sce service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) (Strict Contextual Escaping) is generally used to securely load dynamic HTML.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turned out to be relatively straight forward, so I ended up using ng-bind-html, which strangely enough requires a statement like  embedded in it. Not certain I have understood ng-bind-html.

You need two bits, a section that generates the HTML type tag. So in your controller add

```
var culine = '<iframe src="' + fside.surl + '" height="700" width="700"></iframe>';
        console.log(culine);
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(culine);
```

Basically, fside.surl can be any string containing a full web address. The second thing is the $sce.trustAsHtml which basically allows you to load from other domains.
The html code looks as follows:

```
<div id="front-page" ng-bind-html="showpane('front')"></div>
```

In this case I use a function called showpane to search for the webpage for the page listed as front, then check that url and return that.
Hope it helps:)